# Akka.net scheduler sends just first value and doesn't update it, How fix it

Tags: akka.net

I can't find the answer to an interesting moment.
in `akka.net` I have the scheduler. It will work in actor which are sort out a number.

here a simple implementation

```
_statusScheduler = Context.System.Scheduler.ScheduleTellRepeatedlyCancelable(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_shedulerInterval),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_shedulerInterval),
            _reporterActor,
            new ProgressReport(requestId, _testedQuantity),
            Self);
```

> where
>
> _shedulerInterval - 5-second interval,
>
> _testedQuantity - quantity of tested number all time updated.

and after 5 seconds it is sent 0; always, not a changed number. And here is a question: is it possible to send updated quantity?

I can't send the message to the updating quantity from `Recieve<>` methods, because my actor is handled the counting message and it is counted the quantity all the time and updated it(when it finished it will receive next message). But all five seconds I should generate a report by a scheduler. Is it possible to fix it?

I think now I need to send all logic because it works fine, and the stone of my problem is scheduler behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is that the message you pass into the scheduler, `new ProgressReport(requestId, _testedQuantity)`, is what is going to be sent each time. Since you're passing in those integer values by value, the object is going to have the original values for those fields at the time you created the message and therefore the message will never update.

If you want to be able to change the content that is sent in the recurring scheduler, do this instead:

```
var self = Self; // need a closure here, since ActorContext won't be available
_statusScheduler = Context.System.Scheduler.Advanced.ScheduleRepeatedlyCancelable(interval, interval, () => {
  _reporterActor.Tell(new ProgressReport(requestId, _testedQuantity), self);
});
```

This usage of the scheduler will generate a new message each time when it invokes the lambda function and thus you'll be able to include the updated integer values inside your object.

Comment: Thank you for the advice it's a good way, but I took the exception when I init the scheduler (`Self` generate an exception): `System.NotSupportedException: 'There is no active ActorContext, this is most likely due to use of async operations from within this actor.'`

I tried to use the `ActorRef.NoSender`, but it broke my scheduler.

Comment: ah, that's a bug - need to close over `Self` in my example.